# symfony 3.1 repository method confusion

Tags: symfony

I have a repository with this method:

```
public function getCountryId($code_2a)
{
    return $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('e')
        ->andWhere('e.code2a = :code_2a')
        ->setParameter('code_2a', $code_2a)
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
}
```

and a controller with this call:

```
$country = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Countries')->getCountryId('GB');
```

As I understand in $country I will have an entity with the data of the record of the table, 'Great Britain' in this case.

But if in the controller I do:

```
$country_id = $country->getId();
```

I get an exception:

```
Error: Call to a member function getId() on array
```

And this confuses me. How can I get the `$id` of the country?

Answer (score 4):

Your query return an array which contains object(s) so if you're expecting to receive only one object you have to change your query using `getOneOrNullResult`

```
public function getCountryId( $code_2a )
{
    return $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('e')
        ->andWhere('e.code2a = :code_2a')
        ->setParameter('code_2a', $code_2a)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getOneOrNullResult()
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the controller

```
$country = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Countries')->findOneByCode2a('GB');
if($country) {
    $country_id = $country->getId();
}
```

Return one object Country. If you use findBy, return array with objects.

Comment: Thanks DOZ. Both messages helped me.